# python3: can't open file 'tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I've installed tensorflow(CPU) version 1.9.0
This script does not exist in the required directory. Is there something wrong in my installation or am I supposed to manually download from Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the [Simple Audio Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) tutorial, you should check out the repository manually first to get the scripts. These are not installed when you install TensorFlow with pip.

Please complete the following steps to start the training:

1. Download the TensorFlow repository: `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git`
2. Enter the repository directory: `cd tensorflow`
3. Switch to the version 1.9 branch: `git checkout r1.9`
4. Now you can run the train script: `python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py`